# How to get first n characters of file in unix

Tags: unix

I have to check the file name is >45 characters
If so I need to rename the file name with 1st 45 characters.

suppose my file name is 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.txt then my file name should be renamed to 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f=12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.txt
touch $f
mv $f "`echo $f|cut -c1-45`.txt"
```

Comment: To avoid hardcoding the file extension, you can use sed. Note that this will fail if the filename has multiple periods tho. `$ echo '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.txt' | sed -r -e 's/^([^\.]{0,45}).*\.(.*)$/\1\.\2/'` `->` `123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This should work (assuming `$f` is the variable containing file name):

```
[[ ${#f} -gt 45 ]] && mv "$f" "${f:0:45}"
```

Comment: This only works in Bash. Other Bourne-like shells don't have `[[` or `${...:...:...}`.

Comment: @pts: Yes older shells won't have it but all modern Unix, Linux, OSX systems these days are shipped with bash as default shell.

Comment: @anubhava *Many*, perhaps even *most*, but definitely not *all*...

Comment: @anubhava It is to me, but it's better not to exaggerate...

Comment: @twalberg: There is no point in arguing about it since OP didn't select this answer as accepted and I had already commented `Yes older shells won't have it`